# How to show image popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

http://www.kampyle.com/software-feedback-analytics

On this url clicking on image it's become popup, clicking on popup image show the next one. **How to do it?** When popup show feedback image on right corner does not hide. **How to do it?** **I also want to know this process name?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: thanks for reply.i want to know this can be possible by css .if i scroll image does not move but i want it.Image move on scroll movement.Thanks again

Comment: sorry i didn't get your point. are you using quite big image and need scrolling in the popup?